# Disabling MySQL "secure-file-priv" option from Homebrew Installation

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I had to reinstall MySQL 5.6 on OSX 10.12.4 with Homebrew 1.1.11 (mysql@5.6 formula) and this is the first time I've seen this issue. Basically, the new install appears to be enabling the --secure-file-priv option.

```
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

This is a well documented question and I've read the threads but none of them seem to speak to where Homebrew sets this option? All of the file locations mentioned don't appear for my installation of MySQL.

I just need to disable the option, I don't want to specify a specific folder. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else that runs into this issue, you can solve the problem by placing a `.my.cnf` in your home directory containing:

```
[mysqld_safe]
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv=""
```